# Superclass and subclass resolution?

Tags: java, inheritance, radix, derived-class

I am new to java programming and very new to stackoverflow too.Came across this simple code which I failed to understand.Please help me how this works

```
class Base {
 public static void foo(Base bObj) {
 System.out.println("In Base.foo()");
 if(bObj instanceof Base){
     System.out.println("Base instance");
 }
 bObj.bar();
 }

 public void bar() {
     System.out.println("In Base.bar()");
     }
    }
    class Derived extends Base {
     public static void foo(Base bObj) {
     System.out.println("In Derived.foo()");
     bObj.bar();
     }
     public void bar() {
     System.out.println("In Derived.bar()");
     }
    }
    class Downcast {
     public static void main(String []args) {
     Base bObj = new Derived();
     bObj.foo(bObj);
     }
    }
```

Now here i get

```
In Base.foo()
Base instance
In Derived.bar()
```

Though I got how it goes `base.foo()`.But how derived.It also prints that it is an instance of a base object then how derived.The explanation given was that earlier it did static resolution and later dynamic.What is static and dynamic resolution.

I though the concept goes as

```
Base b=new Derived();
```

This means we create a derived object which is then upcasted to Base.So why not it calls base.bar()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `static` methods are not overridden. If you declare a `static` method in a child class which has the same signature as a `static` method in the parent class, it is said to hide it.

Comment: You mean the static method in the child class goes hidden or the parent class?

Comment: The child class method hides the parent class method. Polymorphism also doesn't apply to `static` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the core of what polymorphism is all about. Objects in Java try to behave the same way as real objects.

Bikes usually have 3 gears.

Competion bikes are bikes. But they have 18 gears.

If I show you a competition bike and ask you "Is it a bike", the answer is yes, right. But if I ask you "How many gears does this bike have", you'll answer "18", because although it's a bike, it's a specialized type of bike which doesn't have 3 gears as common bikes, but 18.

It's the same with Java objects:

```
Base bObj = new Derived();
```

is the same as

```
Bike bike = new CompetitionBike();
```

I.e. you're constructing a bike, and the concrete type of the bike is "competition bike". So, if you ask the bike how many gears it has, the answer will be 18:

```
bike.getGears(); // 18
```

Similarly,

```
bObj.bar();
```

will invoke the bar() method that is defined in the concrete type of the object, which is Derived. So "In Derived.bar()" will be printed.

Static methods don't follow these rules, because static methods are not invoked on objects, but on classes.

Calling `bObj.foo(bObj)` is legal, but is extremely bad practice. What you should call is either `Base.foo()`or `Derived.foo()`, depending on which method you want to call. And the method defined on the given class will be called. When you do the *wrong* thing and call `bObj.foo()`, the compiler actually translates `bObj` to the *declared* type of `bObj`, which is `Base`.

Comment: Wooo..Didn't even take me a second to understand all this.This was superb.

Answer (score 1):

You have come across the difference between static and nonstatic methods.

Static methods are called according to the type of the class that calls them. For example, in your case `Base b = new Derived();`, `b.staticMethod()` is called from `Base`.  This is why you should never call static methods from objects - its unnecessary because you could call `Base.staticMethod()`

However, if `b.nonstaticMethod()` is called, the nonstatic method from the Derived class will be called. This is how Java manages inheritance.

For further reading, I would suggest reading the [Java Tutorial on Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)